# dhcp client on linux, port or use?

Tags: c++, linux

On linux platform, I want to have dhcp client.

port any open source client to my app (which seems to be a bit time consuming)?
or communicate with the standalone client app via Signals?
or anyone knows any dhcp client library?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want your app to tell the computer to DHCP?  I would talk to [dhcpcd](http://www.phystech.com/download/dhcpcd_man.html) using command line arguments and not do tons of extra work.

Comment: to be more clear, I want to configure ip settings automatically and in some case give possibility to set it manuelly.  I wonder dhcpcd can also accept some manuel settings on commandline instead of getting it from server.
thanks...